# Counting the nodes of any tree time improvement

Tags: c, tree

I have to make a function which counts how many elements my tree have. My tree is not binary, is the most general kind of tree.

The node is:

```
typedef struct node{
char item;
int number_of_sons;
node **sons;
}
```

My counting function is this

```
void numbering(node *HT,int ok=0)
{
    static int number = 0;
    if (ok == 1)
    {
        printf("%d", number);
        return;
    }
    if (HT == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    else 
    {
        number++;
        for (int i = 0;i < HT->nr_of_sons;i++)
        {
            numbering(HT->next[i], 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to improve this function to make this faster? 
EDIT: the way I use this function is:

```
int main()
{
//create tree;
 numbering(tree,0);
 numbering(tree,1);
}
```

When I call the function the second time it prints my result

Comment: What is the purpose of the `ok` variable?  It seems to always be zero.

Comment: Ok is an implicit parameter, which make the function got 2 uses. With ok=0 it counts how many nodes I got, With ok=1 the function prints the number of nodes.

Comment: Seems as though `ok` enables some trace code, for debugging purposes.

Comment: Unrelated (at least until the indexing loop is implemented), there is *no* reason for the `number_of_sons` to be *signed*. it should be an unsigned type, and ideally, due to its count-of-objects nature, a `size_t`. You'll never have a -N number of sons, so don't allow it from the start.

Comment: You meant `//`, right?

Comment: @Bob__ right!, sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very strange recursive function there--you're using a static variable in the function which is never reset, so the function can only be used once per program run!

I'd rewrite it this way:

```
size_t nodecount(node *root)
{
    size_t count = 0;
    if (root)
    {
        count++;
        for (int i = 0; i < root->nr_of_sons; i++)
        {
            count += nodecount(root->sons[i]);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

If you really want to speed things up, you could augment your node structure by adding a `size_t subtree_count` field which you'd maintain whenever you insert or remove nodes.  Another idea is to compact the pointer-to-array-of-sons into the node structure directly:

```
typedef struct node{
    char item;
    int number_of_sons;
    node_t *sons[0];
} node_t;
```

What I've done here is made it so the `sons` variable is an array rather than a pointer to an array.  But it has size zero (n.b. use `[]` or `[1]` if your compiler requires), because you don't know the number of sons at compile time.  But you can simply allocate nodes with the right amount of space:

```
node_t* tree = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t) + num_sons*sizeof(node_t*));
```

This reduces pointer indirection by one layer, which may help performance.

Comment: I understand now. Never knew indirection could affect performace so much( I have to store like 10K elements).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is better and more efficient:

```
int numbering(node *HT)
{
    if (!HT)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int num = 1;
    for (int i = 0;i < HT->nr_of_sons;i++)
    {
        num += numbering(HT->next[i]);
    }
    return num;
}
```

I deleted your ok variable and changed the returned value from void to int.

1. In the case base you return 0;
2. For the leaf so they will return 1;
3. For inner nodes they will return 1 + the numbers of nodes in the
   subtree.